# Como criar uma lista a partir de um JSON com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suponha-se que eu tenha o seguinte dado JSON:

```html
const dados = {"animais":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Max",
    "tags":"Border Collier"
  },{
    "id":2,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Fini",
    "tags":"Lhasa Apso"
  },{
    "id":3,
    "tipo":"Gato",
    "nome":"Luna",
    "tags":"Siames"
  },{
    "id":4,
    "tipo":"Papagaio",
    "nome":"Loro",
    "tags":"Curica"
  },{
    "id":5,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Rock",
    "tags":"Pitbull"
    }
  ]
}
```

E eu precise gerar uma lista da seguinte maneira:

```html
const dados = {
  "Cachorros":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Max",
        "tags":"Border Collier"
      },{
        "id":2,
        "nome":"Fini",
        "tags":"Lhasa Apso"
      },{
        "id":5,
        "nome":"Rock",
        "tags":"Pitbull"
      }],
  "Gatos":[{
        "id":3,
        "nome":"Luna",
        "tags":"Siames"
      }],
  "Papagaios":[{
        "id":4,
        "nome":"Loro",
        "tags":"Curica"
     }
  ]
}
```

Qual seria a forma mais rápida ou fácil de se fazer tal transformação? Estou aprendendo Javascript agora e preciso tratar esses dados de uma API para exibi-los em uma tabela. Minha lógica ainda está fraca, dei uma pesquisada nos métodos filter, map e reduce mas não consegui imaginar uma forma de o fazer.

Depois, teria como eu calcular por exemplo, quantos cachorros existem na nova lista? E gatos e Papagaios. Imagino que essa parte seja a mais fácil usando um length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar o reduce para fazer isso:

```
const animais = dados.animais.reduce((obj, animal) => {
  const tipo = animal.tipo + 's'; 
  const {nome, id, tags} = animal;
  obj[tipo] = (obj[tipo] || []).concat({nome, id, tags});
  return obj;
}, {});
```

O que isso faz é percorrer a array de `Animais` e ir gerando propriedades com o nome do tipo do animal que sejam arrays. E juntar as arrays uma a uma, reconstruíndo a estrutura desses dados.

Juntei `+ 's'` para criar plurais... mas podias simplificar usando o tipo em singular.

Exemplo:

```js
const dados = {
  "animais": [{
    "id": 1,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Max",
    "tags": "Border Collier"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Fini",
    "tags": "Lhasa Apso"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "tipo": "Gato",
    "nome": "Luna",
    "tags": "Siames"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "tipo": "Papagaio",
    "nome": "Loro",
    "tags": "Curica"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Rock",
    "tags": "Pitbull"
  }]
};

const animais = dados.animais.reduce((obj, animal) => {
  const tipo = animal.tipo + 's'; 
  const {nome, id, tags} = animal;
  obj[tipo] = (obj[tipo] || []).concat({nome, id, tags});
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(animais, null, 2));
```

No caso de haver mais propriedades, para ficar mais genérico poderia fazer-se assim:

```js
const dados = {
  "animais": [{
    "id": 1,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Max",
    "tags": "Border Collier"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Fini",
    "tags": "Lhasa Apso"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "tipo": "Gato",
    "nome": "Luna",
    "tags": "Siames"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "tipo": "Papagaio",
    "nome": "Loro",
    "tags": "Curica"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "tipo": "Cachorro",
    "nome": "Rock",
    "tags": "Pitbull"
  }]
};

const ignorar = ['tipo'];

function copiarExcepto(original, excluirProps) {
  return Object.keys(original)
  .filter(prop => !excluirProps.includes(prop)) // excluir as chaves que não interessam
  .reduce((obj, prop) => {
    // adicionar as chaves relevantes ao novo objeto
    return { ...obj,
      [prop]: original[prop]
    }
  }, {});
}

const animais = dados.animais.reduce((obj, animal) => {
  const tipo = animal.tipo + 's'; // criar a chave por tipos
  const novoObjeto = copiarExcepto(animal, ignorar); // copiar o objeto sem as chaves que não queremos
  obj[tipo] = (obj[tipo] || []).concat(novoObjeto); // adicionar o animal à lista
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(animais, null, 2));
```

Comment: Não era melhor manter as propriedades todas do objeto e retirar apenas a do tipo (com Object.assign e delete por exemplo) ? Dessa forma a solução fica mais genérica e não descarta potenciais propriedades extra que os objetos tenham.

Comment: @Isac sim e não, usar `delete` muda o objeto fora da função, cria efeitos secundários e bugs dificeis de detetar. Nesse caso seria melhor ter uma array com uma lista de propriedades a não copiar, e usar `Object.keys` para filtrar antes de copiar o objeto com as restantes _N_ propriedades. Vou juntar um exemplo disso na resposta.

Comment: Poderia explicar com comentários no código ou links o que cada parte do código faz? Como o autor da pergunta colocou na própria: **Estou aprendendo Javascript agora**, acho que o código por si só ta bem complexo para um iniciante não?!

Comment: @LeAndrade juntei comentários no segundo exemplo. Se houver alguma linha que não saibas o que faz diz, que explico melhor!

Comment: Da minha parte ta de boa, eu digo pelo autor da pergunta, que é iniciante, ele poderá pegar o código pronto e utilizá-lo, mas, será que estaria sabendo o que está acontecendo por detrás do código sem os comentários.

Comment: @LeAndrade pois, é difícil saber. O código é pouco, mas se for preciso ajuda cá estarei para ajudar o autor da pergunta ou outros que precisem :)

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado pela resposta, ela com certeza foi de grande valor, irei dar mais uma estudada a respeito do map, filter e reduce. Agora fica mais um questionamento. Se eu precisasse gerar um objeto que contem somente os arrays com menos de 3 animais, faria como? Exemplo, há 3 cachorros, mas não há 3 gatos e 3 papagaios, como eu faria pra segregar os papagaios e gatos dos cachorros gerando um novo objeto?

Comment: @LucasMorse nesse caso terias de revisitar esses arrays depois de serem criados e apagar os que tenham `array.length < 3`.  Podias também fazer isso antes de criar a propriedade.. mas é mais simples no final. Se não encontrares uma resposta aqui no site que cubra esse caso faz uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

Talvez a maneira que fiz não seja o modo mais performático, mas, deixo aqui um exemplo de como pode ser feito utilizando métodos do Javascript como [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) e [object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const dados = {"animais":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Max",
    "tags":"Border Collier"
  },{
    "id":2,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Fini",
    "tags":"Lhasa Apso"
  },{
    "id":3,
    "tipo":"Gato",
    "nome":"Luna",
    "tags":"Siames"
  },{
    "id":4,
    "tipo":"Papagaio",
    "nome":"Loro",
    "tags":"Curica"
  },{
    "id":5,
    "tipo":"Cachorro",
    "nome":"Rock",
    "tags":"Pitbull"
    }
  ]
}

let dog = dados.animais.filter(x => x.tipo == 'Cachorro');      // filtra cada tipo de animal
let cat = dados.animais.filter(x => x.tipo == 'Gato');
let parrot = dados.animais.filter(x => x.tipo == 'Papagaio');

let objeto = {                                                 // cria um objeto modelo
  Cachorros: [],
  Gatos: [],
  Papagaios: []
}

Object.assign(objeto.Cachorros, dog);           // transforma o resultado do filter em objeto
Object.assign(objeto.Gatos, cat);
Object.assign(objeto.Papagaios, parrot);

for(let i in objeto.Cachorros) delete objeto.Cachorros[i].tipo;  // retira "tipo" dos objetos
for(let i in objeto.Gatos) delete objeto.Gatos[i].tipo;
for(let i in objeto.Papagaios) delete objeto.Papagaios[i].tipo;

console.log(objeto);
console.log('Quantidade de cachorros: ', objeto.Cachorros.length);
console.log('Quantidade de gatos: ', objeto.Gatos.length);
console.log('Quantidade de papagaios: ', objeto.Papagaios.length);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Andrade. Mas e se eu tiver um JSON com um numero enorme de tipos de animais diferentes, existem uma forma de fazer sem instanciar um let dog, etc? Por exemplo, usando um while ou um for para percorrer o Array.

Comment: Foi como comentei, dependendo dos dados não fica performático, deixei apenas como um exemplo mesmo, até tem como fazer sem criar as variáveis, mas, ficaria mais complexo. A reposta do @Sergio é perfeita,pq, independe da quantidade de itens nos arrays além de ser bem enxuta, apesar de ser mais complexa para quem está aprendendo, se tiver dúvidas quanto a resposta dele pode questioná-lo.

Answer (score -2):

Ola, é bem, simples!

```
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

const dados = {
  "Cachorros":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Max",
        "tags":"Border Collier"
      },{
        "id":2,
        "nome":"Fini",
        "tags":"Lhasa Apso"
      },{
        "id":5,
        "nome":"Rock",
        "tags":"Pitbull"
      }],
  "Gatos":[{
        "id":3,
        "nome":"Luna",
        "tags":"Siames"
      }],
  "Papagaios":[{
        "id":4,
        "nome":"Loro",
        "tags":"Curica"
     }
  ]
}

dados.Cachorros.forEach(myFunction)


function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  appDiv.innerHTML = appDiv.innerHTML + value.nome + "<br>"; 
}
```